# Method that takes any setter as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, lang

I have an Item class

```java
public class Item {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Boolean isGood;

// getters and setters
}
```

And I want to declare a method that can take a method reference and some value as arguments.

What I tried

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item = new Item();
        
        setLong(item::setId, 123L);
        setBool(item::setGood, true);
        setString(item::setName, "Foo Bar");

   }

   static void setLong(Consumer<Long> setter, Long o) {
        setter.accept(o);
    }

    static void setBool(Consumer<Boolean> setter, Boolean o) {
        setter.accept(o);
    } 
    
    static void setString(Consumer<String> setter, String o) {
        setter.accept(o);
    }
}
```

But I want something like

```java
set(Long.class, item::setId, 123L);
set(Boolean.class, item::setGood, true);
set(String.class, item::setName, "Foo Bar");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use generics: `static <T> void set(Consumer<? super T> setter, T value) { setter.accept(value) }`. Though I'm not sure if this abstraction is useful (what does this gain you over just calling the setter itself?).

Comment: @Slaw I guess if we're being ***really*** pedantic, you get the benefit of making sure your inputs don't experience primitive widening. If your setter asks for a `long`, you can't give it an `int`. Depending on what the original problem is, this could be useful for a very narrow use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```java
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class SOQ_20220528
{

   public static class Example
   {
   
      private Short a;
      private Integer b;
      private Long c;
   
      public Example() {}
   
      public Short getA() {
         return this.a;}
      public Integer getB() {
         return this.b;}
      public Long getC() {
         return this.c;}
   
      public void setA(Short a) {this.a = a;}
      public void setB(Integer b) {this.b = b;}
      public void setC(Long c) {this.c = c;}
      
      public String toString() { 
         return this.a + " " + this.b + " " + this.c; }
   
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      final Example instanceName= new Example();
      
      final Short tuv = 1;
   
      set(Short.class, instanceName::setA, Short.valueOf(tuv));
      set(Integer.class, instanceName::setB, Integer.valueOf(2));
      set(Long.class, instanceName::setC, Long.valueOf(3));
   
   }
   
   public static <T> void set(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> setter, T value)
   {
   
      setter.accept(value);
   
   }

}
```

We place the Class of the type we want to use as the first parameter, then we put the setter as our second parameter, and finally, we put the literal value we want our object to adapt as our third parameter.

The first parameter is necessary because of type erasure at runtime. Java simply doesn't keep the type at runtime, so we just need to pass in the Class, which functions as our runtime type.

The second parameter is necessary, as you need a setter to perform. However, notice that I did `instanceName::setA` instead of `Example::setA`. Since this is the section of the code where we are ***providing*** the consumer to use, I am using the ***instance*** name instead of the ***type*** name. There are many times where it will actually be the other way around (one example is with static methods).

The third parameter is the actual value that will be the parameter of the setter. I am setting field `a` of `instanceName` to be the `Short` value `1`. That `1` portion is the third parameter I am talking about.

**EDIT** - turns out that for this particular example, the `Class<T>` parameter is not necessary. I will leave it in for simplicity of modification, but yes, you could technically have a method header like this instead --  `public static <T> void set(Consumer<T> setter, T value)`, then you would supply the parameters to this method the same as before, just without the class.

Comment: With how `set` is currently implemented, the `clazz` parameter is actually useless. The `T` will be inferred from the other two parameters, and we trust the compiler to only allow legal types.

Comment: @Slaw I thought a left a comment, but maybe I was mistaken. Thank you, I have edited my solution in response